# How to know that Download has been completed

Tags: vaadin

I am sending a file for download at client browser by using the following code:-

```
    FileDownloadResource fdr = new FileDownloadResource(file, app);
    btnGet.getWindow().open(fdr);
```

Everything works fine but when I add `file.delete();` after that, I get exception `File or directory does not exist`. I can understand before the download component is done with the file, the file is getting deleted. Is there some way to get notification that download is complete and its safe to delete the file from server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161460/how-to-detect-when-vaadin-filedownloader-succeeds-or-fails. I suppose one workaround would be to load the file in the memory and return its input stream, thus the resources will be freed when it's closed. But that depends on how big the file is. Another wild thought would be to implement your own _input stream_ which removes the file when it's closed.