# How to detect when FileDownloader in vaadin finish

Tags: java, csv, vaadin

How can I detect fileDownloader finish to export my csv-file:

Here is the part, where I implemented the download-button

```
 Button downloadButton = new Button("Download");
    Exporter exporter = new Exporter();
    downloadButton.addClickListener(clickEvent -> {
     //something here
    });
    exporter.getFileDownloader().extend(downloadButton);
```

This is my exporter with the fileDownloader:

```
class Exporter{
    private FileDownloader fileDownloader;

    Exporter() {
        StreamResource streamResource = createResource();
        fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(streamResource);
    }

    private StreamResource createResource() {
        return new StreamResource(new StreamResource.StreamSource() {
            @Override
            public InputStream getStream() {
            // some logic here
            }
        }, "myfile.csv");
    }

    FileDownloader getFileDownloader() {
        return fileDownloader;
    }

    ...
```

Comment: You could try wrapping the input stream

Answer (score 1):

I checked official documentation, it seems there is no way to detect that using FileDownloader. There is also similar thread you can check it. [How to detect when Vaadin FileDownloader succeeds or fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161460/how-to-detect-when-vaadin-filedownloader-succeeds-or-fails)